# AAM and ASM with opencv 2.4.3

Tags: opencv

Can anyone suggest me about AAM or ASM code?(Not only demo or from book because I read it but cannot do it the same as the OPENCV book) with opencv 2.4.3 C++ because I have to apply this 2 algorithms to find ROI of face.

Best Thank 
Chairat(Thailand)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get AAM and ASM code in [vosm library](http://www.visionopen.com/downloads/open-source-software/vosm/) but this is not the best way to find face ROI. Haar cascades much better for this task. AAM and ASM usually used for finding facial feature points, and they need already defined face region. Another ASM code you can find here: https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code  (see chapter 6).

Comment: Best Thank if I have another question could I asking you by email?